# Find if a XML file contains a specific namespace using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Does anyone know if I can find out if my xml file contains a certain namespace (where no elements are given that name).

Somthing among the lines of

`<xsl:if test="count(xmlns:name)!=0" >`

`</xsl:if>`

this does not work, as I get the error "the prefix xmlns" is not defined.

Comment: When you say "where no elements are given that name", do you mean you are only looking for namespaces that are not used in any element name, or do you mean that you are looking for the namespace whether or not it is used in an element name?

Comment: Hi, I sorry I missed your comment earlier. I mean whether or not it is used in an element name. @michael.hor.257k had a good solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> find out if my xml file contains a certain namespace (where no elements are given that name).

It is difficult to understand what exactly you mean by that. If you want to find out if the input XML contains a **namespace declaration** using a given namespace URI, regardless of whether this declaration is used to place any of the XML's nodes in said namespace or not, you can use a test in the form of:

```
<xsl:if test="//namespace::*[.='your-namespace-URI']">
```

Example:

**XML**

```
<root xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/a">
    <item>Alpha</item>
    <item>Bravo</item>
    <item>Charlie</item>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:if test="//namespace::*[.='http://example.com/a']">YES</xsl:if>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>YES</result>
```

The result here is positive, even though the XML has no nodes that are actually in the `"http://example.com/a"` namespace.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can check e.g. `//pf:*` while declaring `xmlns:pf="http://example.com/ns"` in your XSLT code to check if there are any elements in the namespace `http://example.com/ns`. Or you can check `//*[namespace-uri() = 'http://example.com/ns']` without declaring the namespace in the XSLT. Both checks assume that namespace means a certain namespace URI and not a certain prefix.